# How to horizontally scroll text in multiple text view android

Tags: android, textview, horizontal-scrolling

I want to horizontally scroll the text in 2 text view. But it is scrolling only in one text view using following code. But another text view is not scrolling. Solution is high appreciated.

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/zoomableImageView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zoomableImageView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/zoomableImageView">

            <!--File Name-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="File name: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fileName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--File Type-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="File type: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fileType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--File size-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="File size: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fileSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Image Resolution-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Resolution: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageResolution"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Modified Date-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Resolution: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/modifiedDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- File path -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Path: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/path"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="12.5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"  />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Filename text is scrolling but file path text is not scrolling.

Comment: where is your code

Comment: @sasikumar See now

Comment: post your full xml code of that file

Comment: @sasikumar see file name is scrolling but file path is not scrolling.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387142/multiple-textviews-in-a-scrollview

Comment: whether it will scroll automatically??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Comment: @sasi Not working

Comment: @sasi , i want to scroll automatically.

Comment: @Sasi kumar sorry its working. i have to used custom textview mentioned in the link. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:singleLine="true"/>
```

> tvName.setSelected(true); // Automatic Scrolling horizontally