# multiple textviews inside a scrollview with a custom DOT

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

ScrollView is not scrolling when I put my contents inside it. I know I can do compoundDrawableIntrinsic(0,0,0,R.layout.ic_dot) to set the drawable at the bottom of my textview.

as you can see there is Today Persons Rating and a lot many other TextViews. So, what should I use here. I was thinking about putting all these Today Persons Rating....longlist inside a nested scrollview. [I tried the solution here but it did'nt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387142/multiple-textviews-in-a-scrollview)

here is my code for the scrollview

[image: this is the image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"

                android:id="@+id/sv_to_card_items"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:id="@+id/ScrollView">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                    <TextView android:text="Distance"
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="280dip"
                        android:layout_height="60dip">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView android:text="Distance"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="280dip"
                        android:layout_height="60dip">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView android:text="Distance"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="280dip"
                        android:layout_height="60dip">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView android:text="Distance"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="280dip"
                        android:layout_height="60dip">
                    </TextView>


                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </TextView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you need move your ScrollView outside the Toolbar tag

Comment: I did. now it's in appbarlayout but still the same problem. can't scroll.

Comment: I just replaced my scrollview with HorizontalScrollView and it worked! Thanks. @indralesmana